# Do builds on Google Play's Open/Beta Track expire?

Tags: timeline, google-play-console, beta

We released an app on the Open/Beta test Track on Google Play and need to know if the build will expire so we can upload a new build. I've looked at a lot of Google Play Console documentation and around the web and I can't find anything that confirms whether there is an expiration timeline or not, and what it is.

*Apple has a 90 day expiration on TestFlight so we think there is a good chance Google Play has an expiration too.

Answer (score 2):

To this day, there is no expiration for the artifacts published on the Play Console, on any track. You can leave your artifacts on a beta track forever if you want.

You publish a new version on that track them by uploading a version with a higher versionCode.

Hope that helps.